# nginx X-Accel-Redirect via PHP, 404 error

Tags: php, nginx, mp4, x-accel-redirect

I'm trying to serve up a protected mp4 file using nginx X-Accel via PHP but I'm having trouble with configuration, as I am getting a 404 error.  Here's my nginx.conf server block:

```
       server {
                listen       80;
                server_name  localhost;
                root /var/www/example.com;

                location / {
                        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
                }
                location /protected {
                        internal;
                        alias /var/www/uploads;
                }
        }
```

And here's my php file:

```
$aliasedFile = '/protected/' . $filename; //this is the nginx alias of the file path
$realFile = "/var/www/uploads/" . $filename; //this is the physical file path
header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
header('Content-Length: ' .(string)(filesize($realFile)) );
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('X-Accel-Redirect: ' . $aliasedFile);
```

I'm sure I've just made a simple syntax error, but I can't see it.  I have tried adding trailing `/`s to the location and alias to no avail.  Any nginx experts out there?

**UPDATE**  Here's the remainder of my server block:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name server_domain_or_IP;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that your complete configuration file. There is no `location ~ \.php$` section to handle `index.php`. See [this example](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/).

Comment: It's not my complete config, the remainder is in my sites available default file.  I'll add it shortly.  The server finds my index.php file just fine, and executes all my other php files without issue.

Comment: Read [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html), but you seem to have two server blocks, where you probably should only have one.

Comment: yep, that fixed it.  add an answer and I'll accept.  Thanks man.  bonehead move.